# Fusing dfs with equal dimmensions

Tags: r, na, fusion

I would like to fuse 3 data frames (`AA`, `AB` and `BB`) which contain exactly the same dimensions and will never contain a number in the same coordinate (if one contain a number the others will contain a `NA`. Can also be true that a specific coordinate contain `NA` for all data frames). This is my input:

```
AA <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3
            AX-1   NA       120     130    
            AX-2   NA       NA     NA
            AX-3   NA       NA     NA'
AA <- read.table(text=AA, header=T)

AB <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3
            AX-1   100       NA     NA    
            AX-2   NA       180     NA
            AX-3   NA       120     NA'
AB <- read.table(text=AB, header=T)

BB <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3
            AX-1   NA       NA     NA    
            AX-2   150       NA     NA
            AX-3   160       NA     NA'
BB <- read.table(text=BB, header=T)
```

My expected output:

```
Fus <- 'pr_id  sample1  sample2 sample3
            AX-1   100       120     130    
            AX-2   150       180     NA
            AX-3   160       120     NA'
Fus <- read.table(text=Fus, header=T)
```

Some idea to perform this fusion?

Comment: In your other question the dataframe `Fus` is the original data. Are you inventing hometasks for us? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034632/subsetting-one-matrix-based-in-another-matrix

Comment: Dear jogo. I just used the same example, but the context in my real data is different. I know that it seems to be strange, but I really appreciate this community and I would never do questions here just to make people work. Unfortunately, my programming skills are limited and the pipeline that I am working contain steps that I can understand the necessary logic, but I am unable to write a code for that. I understand if the community is unable to help me here. I am anyway grateful for the help that I always received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution giving you a matrix

```
L <- lapply(list(AA, AB, BB), function(x) { row.names(x) <- x[[1]]; as.matrix(x[-1])})
Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), L)
```

If you want a dataframe:

```
L <- lapply(list(AA, AB, BB), function(x) { row.names(x) <- x[[1]]; as.matrix(x[-1])})
X <- Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), L)
as.data.frame(X)  # Fus <- as.data.frame(X)
```

You can do it also in a loop:

```
L <- lapply(list(AA, AB, BB), function(x) { row.names(x) <- x[[1]]; as.matrix(x[-1])})
X <- L[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(L)) X <- ifelse(is.na(X), L[[i]], X)
X
```

or

```
L <- lapply(list(AA, AB, BB), function(x) { row.names(x) <- x[[1]]; as.matrix(x[-1])})
X <- L[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(L)) X[is.na(X)] <- L[[i]][is.na(X)]
X
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define a new operator to perform the addition.

```
"%++%" <- Vectorize(function(x, y) {
  if(is.na(x) && is.na(y)){
    return(NA)
  } else {
    return(sum(c(x, y), na.rm=T))
  }
})

cbind(AA[, 1, drop=F], matrix(as.matrix(AA[, 2:4]) %++% 
                                as.matrix(AB[, 2:4]) %++% 
                                as.matrix(BB[, 2:4]), ncol=3))
#   pr_id   1   2   3
# 1  AX-1 100 120 130
# 2  AX-2 150 180  NA
# 3  AX-3 160 120  NA
```